# How do I make remote call from localhost with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, axios

I have a local NodeJS app that uses Axios to connect to a local server and now I am trying to hit the deployed server.  The call looks like:

```
let apiCall = "https://api.myproduct.io/api/all";
     console.log("making axios call to " + apiCall);
    const resp = await axios
      .get(
        apiCall,
        {
          headers: {
            APIKey: config.API_KEY,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
          },
        },
        { crossdomain: true, credentials: "same-origin" }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("axios response " + response);
        return response;
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        return e;
      });
    return resp;
  }
```

And I have this in my vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: "https://api.myproduct.io",
  },
  transpileDependencies: ["vuetify"],
};
```

However, when I deploy this to AWS and try to GET it via Axios I get:

> making axios call to https://api.myproduct.io/api/all
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at https://api.myproduct.io/api/all. (Reason:
> CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 301.

These calls work from Postman and my mobile app - it's only from my local environment that this fails.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following correctly, you have deployed a website hosted at domain `x.y` and are trying to call an API at `api.myproduct.io`? If that's the case, the CORS headers that `api.myproduct.io` are responding with are what's causing the issue. You should either change the CORS headers in `api.myproduct.io` if you have control over that service. Or use a proxy of sorts to call it from a server you do control that can be registered to the same domain.

In short:
`x.y` calls to `api.myproduct.io` ❌
`x.y` calls to `x.y/products` ✅ (then service that handles /products calls `api.myproducts.io`)

You can learn more about CORS here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: close I think... I have a site hosted on api.myproduct.io and all calls from my local computer go to api.myproduct.io.  I haven't tried to add any CORS to the server because it is working with my mobile app without issue.  So it seems that when I make a call from local to api.myproduct.io the server sees localhost and rejects it?

Comment: Yes, the domain that the browser loads is what's important. if it's not the same domain, or a domain that `api.myproduct.io` allows in, it won't work.

Comment: So because I am using localhost browser to load locally, but submitting via axios, the server sees the request as localhost and thus rejects it?
If I open the server to allow * Origins - isn't that a security risk?